# Import error for package, am i missing an __init__.py

Tags: python

I have a small python project with the following layout:

```
my-project
├── src
│   ├── lib 
│       └── app
│           └── data
│               └── car_sim.py
│
│
│
│
├── ptests 
│   ├── src 
│       └── lib 
│           └── app
│               └── data
│                   └── __init__.py
│                   └── cprofile.py
```

cprofile.py contains:

```
from src.lib.app.data.car_sim import carRules


def my_example_func():
    #some-code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_example_func()
```

When I run **cprofile.py** with the following command:

> $> cd my-project
>
> $> python ptests/src/lib/app/data/cprofile.py

It gives the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

**Am I missing something? I need to make it work from root dir (top level)?**

Comment: Can you try to go inside the `ptests` folder and run the following command: python src/lib/app/data/cprofile.py

Comment: tried, but same error

Answer (score 0):

If you want a folder to be recognized as a package, that would be src in your case, it needs to contain

__ init __.py

Basically, you've answered your own question in it's title.
That file can be empty. I highly suggest you to read python docs on modules, packages and their structure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put this file you need to call the same file directory. It can reduce the probability of error!

Or you can write the full path to the file in the call.just like:

```
from my-project.src.lib.app.data.car_sim import carRules.
```

Or you can try this way.
Add environment variables:

Variable name: PYTHONPATH

Path - the path of the project, like:

```
(E:\PYTHON\my-project.src.lib.app.data.car_sim)
```

The path solution is a common solution to this problem, I think you can give it a try. If it doesn't solve your problem, I think you can follow my advice, take two `.py` files in the same directory, that you can read the information more intuitively, also it won't be big probability current problems, hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/my-project/src")
from src.lib.app.data.car_sim import carRules


def my_example_func():
    #some-code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_example_func()
```